# add a new path to PTYHONPATH and use it for program that is doing it using NSIS

Tags: python, python-2.7, nsis

**Platform**: Windows 7
**Python**: 2.7.3

```nsis
StrCpy $NETWORK_PATH "\\someserver\network\path\here"
DetailPrint "$\n"
DetailPrint "Setting up paths required"
Push "SETX PYTHONPATH $NETWORK_PATH;$NETWORK_PATH\lib"
Call Execute
Push '"C:\Python27\python.exe" setup.py deploy'
Call Execute

Function Execute
    Exch $0
    # execution of the command and return success or failure
FunctionEnd
```

This above is compiled as NSIS installer and run on multiple machines.

**Problem**
`"C:\Python27\python.exe" setup.py deploy` depends on that $NETWORK_PATH for successful execution.

First time when we run it, $NETWORK_PATH is appended to PYTHONPATH environmental variable, but `"C:\Python27\python.exe" setup.py deploy` fails as new PYTHONPATH will be effective only either in new command prompt or in next run.

Is there a way to make the appended PYTHONPATH effective in the same run itself?

Currently, we are running it twice - once for setting PYTHONPATH and accepting the failure, second time it runs successfully.

Another alternative approach we tried is - we made 2 executables, one for setting PYTHONPATH and another for Python Script to run. Then we put both of them in batch script to run.

But my preference is to achieve whole of this in one file and in one run.

Comment: have you tried import sys, and modify sys.path?

Comment: @KennyOstrom we initially had that in the python script itself using sys.path, that way of doing it is running into issues when our servers had DNS issues. So we made installers where we can quickly change the network path to IPs and get the installer ready. For us to edit the python script in all machines became overhead task. :(

Comment: I don't understand the difference. The only system-specific change is setting NETWORK_PATH in the env on different systems, and you already are doing that.

Comment: yes I do it, but it will not be effective for that particular run of installation. It will be effective only in next run, as it starts its own instance/console. So new PYTHONPATH (with network path appended) will be in effect only for the next run.

Comment: Right ... I don't see the difference between doing that in the installer script, or doing that inside the python script. You can't distribute a bug-fix on the python?  You make it sound like you were individually editing the python scripts on every different machine instead of fixing it once and distributing it.

Comment: I cannot make changes to python script frequently as it stays in repo and synced to all machines through repo and it also stays on server, where as NSIS installer stays outside repo that we developed for quick deployment purposes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update the installers environment, it will be inherited by child processes:

```
System::Call 'Kernel32::SetEnvironmentVariable(t "PYTHONPATH", t "$NETWORK_PATH;$NETWORK_PATH\lib")i.r0' ; $0 will be != "0" on success
Push '"C:\Python27\python.exe" setup.py deploy'
Call Execute
```